# Visualforce page on Lightning community portal

Tags: visualforce, lightning, community

I've Visualforce page on Lightning community portal, i need to pass querystring to this page to get data when page loads but when i try to fetch on controller it gives me

> null

```
//Controller code
ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('feeType')
```

Querystring in the url i pass

```
http://mysinstance/my-dashboard?feeType=xx_fee&visaID=xxx0BalG
```

when i print ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters() i see completely different url

```
/apex/VP_PaymentForm?clc=0&isdtp=p1&nonce
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me to get the actual url and querystring

```
 string headerdata= ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('Referer');
```

Hope it helps someone